# Enable and disable scheduled task with PowerShell and variable

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task

if I try to enable and disable a scheduled task with PowerShell this works.

```
Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Name of my task"
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Name of my task"
```

But if I'm trying this with a variable I'll got an error.

```
$TaskName = "Name of my task"

Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "${TaskName}"
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "${TaskName}"
```

How could I do this with the variable?

Edit:

This error occurs.

```
Enable-ScheduledTask : Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (The system could not found the file)
+ Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "${TaskName}"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Enable-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Enable-ScheduledTask
```

Comment: Just use `Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName`

Comment: I've already tried this. This results in the same error.

Comment: "Same error"? What error? Please include all the pertinent information in your question if you want an accurate answer.

Comment: You probably need to specify the `-TaskPath`

Comment: you could also try `Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName | Enable-ScheduledTask` so every information that the Enable Function needs, gets passed through pipeline

Comment: It was an encoding problem. My script was UTF-8 encoded and it seems that the PowerShell console works with ANSI. My task name includes an "ö". An so the name could not be found because the character was wrong interpredted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the curly brackets

```
$TaskName = "Name of my task"

Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$TaskName"
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$TaskName"
```